# Displaying text from multiple components in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I need to display the values most recently selected in a multiple component pickerview in my label

- I have a pickerView with three components, populated by three NSMutableArrays (rowOneItems,rowTwoItems,rowThreeItems).
- I also have an NSLog statement that is correctly showing what the user last selected from the changed component.
- However, I cannot figure out how to show the most recently selected  values in the label properly.

Currently, the label takes the value from the first picker and displays it, but will not properly update the second and third values. Rather it selects the value that's in the same spot as it. For example, if all three arrays had the values of bird, dog, and cat, when I pick 'dog' in the picker view, the label will show three 'dog' values.

What I want to do is display the values of what the user has selected in the pickerview into a label.

```
    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
   inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

//log which row is selected in each component
//this shows the values correctly in output
if(component ==1) {
return NSLog(@"Selected Difficulty: %@",[rowTwoItems objectAtIndex:row]);
}
else if(component ==2) {
return NSLog(@"Selected Duration: %@",[rowThreeItems objectAtIndex:row]);
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Selected Type: %@",[rowOneItems objectAtIndex:row]);
}

//define chosen items
//stuck here. tried using a if else statement as above, but of course that would only return the first value in the label
NSString *chosenType = [rowOneItems objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *chosenDifficulty = [rowTwoItems objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *chosenDuration = [rowThreeItems objectAtIndex:row];


[workoutResults setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@", chosenType, chosenDifficulty, chosenDuration]];
```

}

Just started learning obj-c, so my apologies if this is a total newbie question. Thanks for any guidance you can give me.

Answer (score 2):

That method you've got above is called for a single row's change, and not for all. (So the 'row' variable) isn't useful outside of the row that was just changed. You'll want to call `selectedRowInComponent:`

```
NSString *chosenType = [rowOneItems objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
NSString *chosenDifficulty = [rowTwoItems objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];
NSString *chosenDuration = [rowThreeItems objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:2]];
```

Comment: even with the selectedRowInComponent, it still only changes the first value (type) of the label. I've tried separating them out do different labels, but no change.

Comment: @nniroclax - Confused - if you change the second component, are you saying you see "Selected Difficulty:" print out, but then the difficulty in your workoutResults label doesn't get updated to the new value?

Comment: yes. that's true. I spent way too much time trying to figure out why so I landed up using a workaround. Now instead of displaying it in a label during the didSelectRow, its in an action where it changes the labels when a button is pushed.It looks prettier anyways.I just used this code and modified for the other two components.//code// NSInteger rowOne = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]; // line break //self.workoutTypeLabel.text = [rowOneItems objectAtIndex:rowOne]; Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: I find it hard to believe that my suggested solution didn't work. :-)  Have a good one.